# Identifying an Event based on a Jump in Rolling Variance in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to figure out a way, in Python, how to identify when an event occurs, based on a jump in the rolling standard deviation.

As shown in the plot below, around the 12000th sample, an `event` occurs.  In my Python script, I am currently using a threshold of `0.00051` to signify when that event occurs.  However, sometimes the `event` occurs at `0.0005` and other times the `event` occurs at `0.000495`.

[image]

My question is - how can I algorithmically, in Python, detect this jump in the rolling standard deviation to create the event altert?  Because if I have a threshold set too low, I don't want it to be triggered too early.  And if I run another test, and the threshold is too high, then I don't want the event to not be triggered at all.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

```
def animate(i):
    data = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\data.txt", sep="\[|\]\[|\]",engine = 'python', header = None)
    data = data.iloc[0, ::4]
    data = data.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.split(',')[-1]).astype(float)
    data.pop(0)
    xar = range(len(data))
    yar = pd.DataFrame(data)
    # Starting from sample 1050 to get rid of any initial noise
    yar = yar[1050:12500]
    xar = xar[1050:12500]
    std = yar.rolling(window=2500).std() 


    if (np.any(std>.00051)):
        choices = ["Confirm Event"]
        reply = easygui.buttonbox("Event Alert!, image, choices)
        if reply == "Confirm Event":
            sys.exit(0)

    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot(xar,std)
    ax1.set_title('Rolling Standard Deviation')       


fig, (ax1) = plt.subplots(1, sharex = True)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=.01)
plt.show()
```

**EDIT w/ Code**

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy
import sys
import numpy as np
import easygui
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation


def animate(i):

    data = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\data.txt", sep="\[|\]\[|\]",engine = 'python', header = None)
    data = data.iloc[0, ::4]
    data = data.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.split(',')[-1]).astype(float)
    data.pop(0)
    xar = range(len(data))
    #yar = data.as_matrix()
    yar = pd.DataFrame(data)

    L=2500
    # Starting from sample 1050 to get rid of any initial noise
    yar = yar[1050:len(data)]
    xar = xar[1050:len(data)]

    std = yar.rolling(window=2500).std() 
    std = std.as_matrix()
    #s = [np.std(yar[ii:ii+L]) for ii in range(1050,len(data))]

    yar = data.as_matrix()
    yar = yar[1050:len(data)]
    d = np.diff(yar)
    d2 = d*d

    ## rolling mean of the diff squared:
    SS = [np.mean(d2[ii:ii+L]) for ii in range(1050, len(d2)-L)]

    # compute the F statistic
    F = np.array([SS[ii]/SS[ii+L] for ii in range(1050, len(SS)-L)])
    w = np.where(np.less(F,1))
    F[w]=1/F[w]

    # the x coordinate of the point where shift happens is offset by L from the computed F:
    xi = np.arange(0,len(F))+L

    ax1.clear()
    ax2.clear()
    ax3.clear()
    ax1.plot(xar, std)
    ax2.plot(xi, F)
    ax3.plot(xar, yar)
    ax1.set_title('Rolling Standard Deviation')
    ax2.set_title('F - values')
    ax3.set_title('Original Data')



fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3, sharex = True)
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=1.5)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=.01)
plt.show()
```

And my data looks like the following:

```
[0.013671875, -0.9599609375, -0.005859375][0.013671875, -0.9599609375, -0.005859375][0.013671875, -0.9599609375, -0.005859375][0.0068359375, -0.8193359375, -0.0029296875][0.0068359375, -0.8193359375, -0.0029296875][0.0068359375, -0.8193359375, -0.0029296875][0.0068359375, -0.8193359375, -0.0029296875][0.0068359375, -0.8193359375, -0.0029296875][0.0068359375, -0.8193359375, -0.0029296875][0.0068359375, -0.8193359375, -0.0029296875][0.0068359375, -0.8193359375, -0.0029296875][0.0087890625, -0.990234375, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.990234375, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.990234375, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.990234375, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.990234375, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.990234375, -0.0048828125][0.0068359375, -0.951171875, -0.00390625][0.0068359375, -0.951171875, -0.00390625][0.0068359375, -0.951171875, -0.00390625][0.0068359375, -0.951171875, -0.00390625][0.0068359375, -0.951171875, -0.00390625][0.0068359375, -0.951171875, -0.00390625][0.0068359375, -0.951171875, -0.00390625][0.0068359375, -0.951171875, -0.00390625][0.009765625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.009765625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.009765625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.009765625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.009765625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.009765625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.009765625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.009765625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0068359375, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0068359375, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0068359375, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0068359375, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0068359375, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0068359375, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0068359375, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0068359375, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0087890625, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0087890625, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0087890625, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0087890625, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0087890625, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0087890625, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0087890625, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0087890625, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.005859375][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.005859375][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.005859375][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.005859375][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.005859375][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.005859375][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.005859375][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.005859375][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0087890625, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0087890625, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0087890625, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0087890625, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0087890625, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0087890625, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0068359375, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0068359375, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0068359375, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0068359375, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0068359375, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0068359375, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0068359375, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0068359375, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125]
```

Comment: Are the events fairly infrequent? You could make a rolling fit of a straight line of N points before and after a point of interest - when there is a change in slope, the fit will be best. If the change of slope happens earlier or later, the fit will be worse. This means that a plot of "goodness of fit" will have a well defined minimum. Would that help?

Comment: Yes, the event occurs only once.  Do you know of an example that does something similar to what you are describing?

Comment: I will create an example. Can you give a little more background on how your rolling standard deviation is computed? How many data points are in your average? How different is an "event" - is it a single point in your source data, or a change in noise in the data?

Comment: The rolling standard deviation is computed over a window of 2500 samples (data points).  The event occurs when there is more noise in the data.  So, if I am measuring temperature and around 12,000th sample someone puts a flame near the sensor.  It's a continuous signal.

Comment: It looks like you are trimming your data twice. Once when you set `yar = yar[1050:len(data)]` (which I would write as `yar=yar[1050:]` because it's shorter and I think it does the same thing). And then again when you compute `SS` over a range that is shorter than `d2`; and once more when you compute the `F` value (again, with an offset of 1050). It looks to me like you are not processing anything before sample 3150...

Comment: Incidentally, if you are only interested in the situation where "F value gets bigger" then you don't need the line where we take the reciprocal of F if F is less than 1. Incidentally, the line of code you posted seems to have only 625 data rows...  you might have to post it somewhere else if you need me to have a closer look.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  I believe that this resolved my issue.  One more question I have, is that the F-value changes across different test runs.  With this F-test method, do you think that my threshold value will be more consistent across runs?

Comment: If your sample size is the same, then you will detect (with the same statistical significance) the same jump in standard deviation. If there is more noise present to begin with, you become less sensitive to a small increase in noise (harder to see an increase from 100 to 105 than from 5 to 10). All of this can only be understood by thinking carefully about the statistics. If you need, you can ask a follow-up question on crossvalidated.stackexchange.com - and get real statisticians to help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought about this for quite some time. In fact, I believe you are asking the wrong question (sorry). As was made clear in the comments, the "event" you are looking for is "something that increases the noise in my signal by a significant amount". The correct way to detect this, then, is to do a statistical test of the difference in the standard deviation (variance) between two sets of data.

There is a thing called the F-test that does exactly this. Without boring you with the details, if you have two samples and compute their variance, you can answer the question "is the variance different" with the F test. To do this, you need the test *statistic*, (the ratio of the variances) and the number of degrees of freedom (the number of samples minus one). You can then calculate the probability that the difference is due to chance ("how often would you see a jump this big in two random samples from the same distribution?) - something called the p value. If the p value is small enough, you can say "this wasn't just by chance". Of course when you run 1000 comparisons, you will "by chance" get a 0.1% probability event happening on average one time; so you need to be prepared for some false positives (or accept that you will only see big changes that are VERY unlikely to occur by chance).

I implemented this approach - and the Python code is below. The plots show that the signal changes "in a way that is hard to see"; but after analysis, the point where the change occurs stands out above the others (even though I increased the standard deviation by only 10%).

A thing to note: I am using the `diff` of the sequence as my input to the calculation; this largely takes out the effect of a slowly changing underlying value so you are really looking at the pure noise. This works best if the sampling is such that subsequent samples are independent (i.e. it only really works if the samples have not been low-pass filtered; otherwise, just don't take the diff).

I hope the code is fairly self-explanatory; let me know if you need further clarification. Your threshold can now be set probabilistically, depending on how many false positives you are willing to accept.

[image]

```
# detect a sudden change in standard deviation of a sequence of measurmeents
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy

# a sequence of values with a mean and standard deviation
# and then a sudden change in the standard deviation
mu = 1000       # mean of signal
sigma = 100     # standard deviation of signal
increase = 1.1  # increase in standard deviation
N1 = 10000      # number of datapoints before change
L = 2500        # size of rolling window

# create a series with a slight increase in noise:
before = np.random.normal(mu,sigma,N1)
after = np.random.normal(mu, increase*sigma, N1)

sequence = np.concatenate((before, after), axis=0)

twoD_img = np.histogram2d(range(0,2*N1), sequence, bins=(50,100))

plt.figure();
plt.subplot(4,1,1)
plt.imshow(twoD_img[0].T,aspect='auto', extent = (0, 2*N1, np.min(sequence), np.max(sequence)));
plt.title('input signal')

# rolling standard deviation
s = [np.std(sequence[ii:ii+L]) for ii in range(0,2*N1-L)]

plt.subplot(4,1,2)
plt.plot(s)
plt.title('rolling standard deviation')

# take the differences, and compute the average noise from that 
d = np.diff(sequence)
d2 = d*d

## rolling mean of the diff squared:
SS = [np.mean(d2[ii:ii+L]) for ii in range(0, len(d2)-L)]

# compute the F statistic
F = np.array([SS[ii]/SS[ii+L] for ii in range(0, (len(d2)-2*L))])
w = np.where(np.less(F,1))
F[w]=1/F[w]

# the x coordinate of the point where shift happens is offset by L from the computed F:
xi = np.arange(0,len(F))+L

plt.subplot(4,1,3)
plt.plot(xi, F); 
plt.title('F values')
plt.xlabel('datapoint #')

# compute log of probability that this is by chance:
logProb = np.log(1-scipy.stats.f.cdf(F, dfn=L-1, dfd=L-1))

plt.subplot(4,1,4)
plt.plot(xi, logProb)
plt.title('log probability plot')
plt.xlabel('datapoint #')

# make some space for the labels
plt.subplots_adjust(left=None, bottom=None, right=None, top=None, wspace=0.1, hspace=0.4)

# and draw the result:
plt.show()
```

Comment: Great write-up - thank you!  Do you recommend that I use a threshold on the F-value in order to trigger the "Event Alert"?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I recommend. The level you pick will determine how small of a change you can detect but also how many false positives you will get. The more sensitive, the more false alarms. Makes sense?

Comment: Alternatively if you use the p value you will have a more direct sense of the probability of a false positive - with given sample size you only have to calculate the corresponding F value once.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification!  I'm having some challenges implementing your suggested code into my code (in the original post).  I am receiving a List Index out of range error on the line, `F = np.array([SS[ii]/SS[ii+L] for ii in range(1050, (len(d2)-2*L))])`.  Any suggestions on how to best apply the F-test stat to my code?

Comment: Try `range(1050, len(SS)-L)` - that should prevent the error. Without details of how you are implementing this it's hard to guess...

Comment: I added Edit 1 w/ my current code and my data.  Does it look like I am implementing the F-test correctly?